# is there any efficient way to insert a copy field in titan?

Tags: titan

Is there any efficient way to store a copy of a field with different data type in   Titan?
I am using titan 1.0.0 with Solr as a backend data store ,according to my queries and my backend strategies ,I want to store a field with two different data type in my Solr ( text and string). I have already knew that I can store them separately, but I want to know if it is possible to insert data once while storing it in both fields.